# Hierarchical data problems in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

Do you think this Model-ViewModel implementation is correct? 
Note that Stars (in the VM) is an ObservableCollection of VMs inside another one, and i feel like it decouples the VM from the M because when removing an element from Stars, i still have to delete it's model manually.

Any ideas on how to improve this without using OnCollectionChanged? 
Thanks in advance.

Models:

```
public class Galaxy
{
    public Galaxy(string name, IList<Star> stars)
    {
        Name = name;
        Stars = stars;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Star> Stars { get; set; }
}

public class Star
{
    public Star(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModels :

```
public class GalaxyVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private Galaxy _galaxy;
    private ObservableCollection<StarVM> _stars;

    public GalaxyVM(Galaxy galaxy)
    {
        _galaxy = galaxy;
        _stars = new ObservableCollection<StarVM>(from sys in _galaxy.Stars
                                                  select new StarVM(sys));
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _galaxy.Name; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<StarVM> Stars
    {
        get { return _stars; }
    }
}

public class StarVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private Star _star;
    public StarVM(Star star)
    {
        _star = star;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _star.Name; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an ObservableCollection at all if you don't want to implement OnCollectionChanged?

Comment: Because i need the UI to be updated, i don't want to use it to synchronize the Model and the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's decoupling and there's decoupling.

It's one thing to have a model that doesn't know anything about the implementation details of its views.  That's good.

It's another thing to have a model that can't be used in dynamic views.  If a model class doesn't implement change notification, it's going to be difficult to reliably keep the UI in sync with the state of the model.  You can try and phony up change notification by putting it all into your view classes, but at the end of the day there's going to be code somewhere that changes the state of the model directly, and if it doesn't implement change notification the views aren't going to know about it and the UI will get out of sync.

I probably wouldn't implement an `IList<Star>` property with a public setter in `Galaxy`.  I'd make the `Stars` property of type `StarList`, and create a `StarList` class that implemented `IList<Star>`, unless I had a very good reason not to.

Comment: Thanks Robert, then i guess it would make sense to implement ObservableCollection in the model too, to notify the viewmodel when someone else changed it. Am i right? 
BTW I don't see the point to the change you suggested, enlight me please :)

Comment: A public setter of `IList<Star>` means that anything creating an instance of a `Galaxy` class gets to decide what kind of list the property's going to contain.  That leads to the mistaken impression that you don't care about it as long as it's a list; in fact, you probably need it to implement change notification so that your UI will function.